# can not create file if user specified

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

I logged in windows machine on behalf of admin. Then run .net (c#) console application which creates files in a net folder, everything is ok. But when I run the same app "as administrator" error occures: "The user name or password is incorrect". The fodler has permissions full control for everyone. 
Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: What folder do you use? Are you sure that entered administrator username and password are correct? Maybe user is disabled? Because if Windows can't verify user, then it won't run app on the behalf of that user and .net code won't be executed

Comment: I'm 146% sure credentials are correct and the user is not disabled

Comment: Do you know if the application starts and fails on the file access or if it just won't start? Knowing which happens would making tracking down the problem much easier.

Comment: Best guess: the administrator account you're using to run the program "as admin" either doesn't exist or has a different password on the remote computer.